# import.io connector not doing anything after pressing stop?

Tags: import.io

When I create an import.io connector after recording the connector, I press stop and nothing happens. It just takes me back to the first step.

Is there a set that I am missing or how should I fix it?

I have watched the webinar 'The import io Crawler' on YouTube and followed it step-by-step.

Comment: Hi Colin, Are you trying to us a connector or a crawler? What is the website you were using? Would be happy to take a look.